# Does AWS S3 generate events when you delete the current object version and the previous version becomes current?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When you delete the current S3 object version (which may be either a true version or a delete marker), the previous version becomes current. However, is an S3 event emitted in that case, and if so what is it?

Likewise, if you delete a non-current version, does it generate an event at all?

Comment: Logically, I would think that when the previous version becomes current it should re-emit the event that happened when that version was created: `s3:ObjectCreated:<HTTPMETHOD>` if it is a true version; `s3:ObjectRemoved:DeleteMarkerCreated` if it is a delete marker; or `s3:ObjectRemoved:Delete` if there was no previous version.

Comment: I suggest that you create an AWS Lambda function that prints the incoming event so that you can view it in the log file. Then, trigger that Lambda function in the method you describe. You will then be able to see the details of the event that was received by the Lambda function. Let us know what you discover!